# Show lyrics in a UI element

Tags: foobar2000

I'm using Foobar2000 and want to show lyrics in the tab named "New Tab" (pictured below).

I've come across a few solutions to showing lyrics but they either don't work or are ugly and obtrusive, I'd prefer to have them shown in a panel under the tabs.

[image: foobar2000]

Answer (score 2):

This works if you have the lyrics embedded in the song already. If you don't, you can use LyricsGrabber or something similar to put it there.

With layout editing active, make a new tab and choose text box as the element. Then, right-click in the text box and choose Settings. Either delete what you see in the box or just append this line to the bottom:

```
$if2(%lyrics%,)
```

Turn off layout editing and it should be working. You may need to click on another track and then click back to get the tab to update.